# How to load file created with numpy.savez_compressed?

Tags: python, numpy

I am saving a numpy array using the following `export_vectors` defined below. In this function, I load string values separated by space and then store them as floats in an numpy array.

```
def export_vectors(vocab, input_filename, output_filename, dim):
    embeddings = np.zeros([len(vocab), dim])
    with open(input_filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip().split(' ')
            word = line[0]
            embedding = line[1:]
            if word in vocab:
                word_idx = vocab[word]
                embeddings[word_idx] = np.asarray(embedding).astype(float)

    np.savez_compressed(output_filename, embeddings=embeddings)
```

Here `embeddings` is an `ndarray` of `float64` type.

Although, then when trying to load the file, using:

```
def get_vectors(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return np.load(f)["embeddings"]
```

When trying to do the loading, I am getting the error:

> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
>       (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position
>   10: invalid start byte

Why is this?

Comment: Especially since the file is a `z` compressed, use `np.load(filename)`.  In other words let `load` take care of opening the compressed archive in the right way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably using `open` wrong.
I suspect, you need to give it a flag to use **binary-mode** like ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)):

```
open(filename, 'rb')  # r: read-only; b: binary
```

The docs explain the default-behaviour: `Normally, files are opened in text mode, that means, you read and write strings from and to the file, which are encoded in a specific encoding.`

But you can make it simple and just use the filepath itself (as [np.load](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) is able to take `file-like object, string, or pathlib.Path`):

```
np.load(filename)  # This would be more natural
                   # as it's kind of the direct inverse of your save-code;
                   # -> no manual file-handling
```

(*A simplified rule*: everything which is using general-purpose compression is alway's working with binary-files; not text-files!)